# Jquery .css() hack to make it appear to animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't use jQuery UI or any plugin. I have a parent div that contains elements that can not be effected by it. So I can't do a simple opacity switch.

```
    <img class="badge_ico" rel="28" src="" />
    <div>I <3 Ford</div>
</div>
```

Is there a hack such as `setTimeout()` or something similar that can increment a color to appear to animate from a dark grey to a mid grey? Assuming something can be done if I use RBG (0,0,0) values.

Content's bg color is what I want to increment on hover.

Comment: So if I wrote the code to animate colors (10 lines) here, would that count as a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on it as an automated approach.  Could be better optimized though. :\  Be forewarned that it is somewhat junky code (I have a Social Studies paper to write now :P)

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eC3Pr/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="box">This is a test</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#box
{
    color:white;
    background:#333;
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

#### javascript

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");

box.onclick = function(){
    box.style.background = "#333";
    var current = Math.round(0.2 * 256);
    var step = 1;
    var ms = 10;
    var animation = setInterval(function(){
        current += step;
        var shade = (current).toString(16);
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#" + shade + shade + shade;
        if(parseInt(shade,16) > 0.7 * 256)
            clearInterval(animation);
    },ms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an array of colors and use `setInterval()` to change the colors on an interval:

```
var target_el = $('#target_element'),
    colors    = ['#999', '#666', '#333', '#ccc'],
    index     = 0,
    timer;

target_element.on('mouseenter', function () {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (index in colors) {
            target_el.css({
                'background-color' : colors[index]
            });
            index++;
        } else {
            index = 0;
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle to show the solution at work: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/ZXCjL/2/

Comment: I randomly put some shades of grey into the array, I don't remember off the top of my head which hexadecimal code is which color.